# SceneForm without ARCore with Camera stream background and ExternalTexture issue

Tags: android, sceneform, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement an type of feature which uses camera stream as a background where all rendering logic is handled by *SceneForm*. To render camera stream I'm using *SceneForms* `ExternalTexture`. Camera stream is loaded using *CameraX* `Preview` component and the `ExternalTexture.surface`.

- The first picture represents current implementation in which camera
  stream is automatically rotated by 90degrees (this uses an `ExternalTexture`).
- The second picture represents the *CameraX* `Preview` rendered into
  `SurfaceView`
- The third one is just a `MediaPlayer` video test for checking if the
  `ExternalTexture.surface` is rendering anything.

I'm expecting the `ExternalTexture.surface` *CameraX* stream source orientation to be the same as `MediaPlayer` stream source.

I've tried several things from rotating the `Nodes` in *ScenForm* to changing the UV cordinates of the material to which `ExternalTexture` is bound. The problem seems to be somewhere between the `ExternalTexture` and *CameraX* `Preview` stream but can't pinpoint where it might be.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing my plane obj vertices to

```
# Blender v2.91.0 OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib surface.mtl
o Plane
v -1.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.0000 0.0000
vt 1.0000 1.0000
vt 0.0000 1.0000
vt 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
usemtl None
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1 3/4/1
```